# spring data jpa transaction and state

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I use spring boot with jpa.

```
@Transaction
public void processXXX(Billing billing){
    Party party = getOldParty(billing);
    delete(party);
    createNewParty(billing);
}

@Transaction
public void delete(Party party){
    repository.delete(party);
}

@Transaction
public void createNewParty(Billing billing){
    ...
    repository.save(billing);
}
```

is there a way to be sure delete operation are done before createNewParty is running?

Comment: your delete query is the default `delete` I think you can try custom `delete` with return type int and you can check `delete(party) != 0` then `createNewParty(billing)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, do a [`flush`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#flush--) between `delete` and `save`